# What's the Best Items to Upgrade in FF Four Heroes of Light?

Tags: final-fantasy-the-4-heroes-of-light

Which items are worth upgrading in Four Heroes of Light? I'd like to know on two levels, the best all throughout and the ones I should consider upgrading mid-game (just after the world turns dark).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Early in the game, I recommend upgrading **Krinjh's Sword** and/or **King's Shortsword** (Knife).  They each have both Attack and Magic Attack which will increase with upgrades.  For armor, **Krinjh's Robe** also has Defense and Magic Defense attributes.

Right after the world turns dark, the **Lightbringer** and **Flameblade** swords are useful because of their elements (and the **Mutsonokami** because of its high Attack value).  For armor, **Rolan's Clothes** and **Rikoteh's Clothes** have both Defense and Magic Defense attributes, as do the **Monk Robe** and **Paladin Armor**.

Overall, the best equipment to upgrade overall will depend on two things:

- Your favorite class (What attributes will they get the most utility out of, and what weaknesses do they have.)
- Your best equipment (Wireless Play prizes often start at with higher stats than standard items)

Protip:  When upgrading, if you don't like the gems required to upgrade, you can back out of the Upgrade screen and then try again.  Different gems will be required the next time you enter the screen.